# Mapproxy geotiff support

Tags: geotiff-tiff, mapproxy

I can see that mapproxy advertises both `image/TIFF` and `image/GeoTIFF` as supported formats, but the output of the latter does not seem to contain geocoding information. Have I misconfigured something, or does mapproxy simply not implement this feature as you'd expect?

Comment: Which service do you use for reading the output?

Comment: When you request images from the MapProxy server, you know the coordinates, either by an using an explicit bounding box or by using a tile index related to some tile matrix. The returning images do not need to include the geocoding information.

Comment: We are using mapproxy as part of a broader suite of services to extract imagery. The output format needs to be geocoded geotiffs, so it would be useful if mapproxy could encode the information for us, to save us having to do it ourselves after we retrieve the imagery.